# Slider banner with text in wordpress

Tags: wordpress

I am new to wordpress.I have a banner along with text, I searched for plugins but most of them are only image banners. I need image along with their relevant text. Following is the screen shot of what I  have explained:
[image]

Comment: you can create your own slider with any jquery plugin. like this http://tympanus.net/Tutorials/FullscreenSlitSlider/index2.html

Comment: you can also try this http://www.jssor.com/

Answer (score 0):

You can create post type using register_post_type function on functions.php file with "Slider" title. so that displaying "Slider" Menu on wordpress admin.

After that, You can add title, content and feature image from admin panel and display Slider in front end using Wordpress function query_posts.